# When execution a Tk-button's function and creating a label inside it, the gui does not update immediately

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm new in the python language and have been learning and working with it for 2 days now.
I'm writing a code to send grbl files to my cnc-machine.

my code:

```
    def grbl_sturing(Gcode_file):

         print('running')
         lbl_Running = Label(root, text="running")
         lbl_Running.grid(row=0, column=2)

         #Grbl setup
         poort = serial.Serial('com11',115200)
         code = open(Gcode_file,'r');
         poort.write(b'\r\n\r\n')
         time.sleep(2)   
         poort.flushInput() 
 
         #sturing 
         for line in code:
              l = line.strip() 
              print ('Sending: ' + l)
              poort.write(l.encode() + b'\r\n') 
              grbl_out = poort.readline()
              print (' : ' + str(grbl_out.strip()))
 
         #Grbl afsluiten
         code.close()
         poort.close()
```

So when i press a button in my tkinter window i go to this fucntion. My intensions where to let me know in a label and in my cmd that the program is sending/running.
But when i press this button my cmd show this:

```
running
Sending: $H
 : b'ALARM:9'
```

Don't mind the alarm its because the cnc-machine isn't powered.

In the cmd it works like itended but when i look in my tkinter window it runs first and when its done it shows me that it is running. Why does it do this and how can i fix it? thank you in advance.

ps(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Where do you update your label? How does your code get called? as function on a button? labal Updates happen as part of eventhandling of the mainloop .

Comment: Like i said im new with this. So i don't know exactly what you mean by that. 
I create a new label evertime i press the button or am i wrong?

Comment: Hey, I am not sure I get what's the intended behavior here, Looking at the code, first ti should print running, which it does, then open a serial communication, read from it and print "sending", it seems to be that its working in order, unless I am misunderstanding what your mean by your issue. Can you kindly clarify?

Comment: To reply to your last message, No, you are reassigning the same label as far as I can see it here.

Comment: My intension where that when i press the button it shows a label that says my code is sending to the cnc_machine before actually sending the file. But what is does now is first sending the file to my cnc and than showing the label.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, let me think for a minute.

Comment: Could you run something like TK.update() after creating the label?

Comment: So i tried to do it like this 
    print('running')
    lbl_Running = Label(root, text="running")
    lbl_Running.grid(row=0, column=2)
    TK.update()
But now is says : NameError: name 'TK' is not defined

Comment: You need to replace TK with whatever name you have for your TKinter variable

Comment: I tried it and it works thank you very much

Comment: Alright, i will post it as an answer and you can accept it if it works, so it can help people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what is happening here is that you are creating the label, but the GUI isn't updating until later, to make it update in that order you must use the line:

```
 TK.update()
```

Where TK is your tkInter variable to force the interface to update at that point, instead of waiting for the main loop.